# How to extract registered information?

Tags: go, go-cobra, cobra

I'm using cobra with my Golang application. How can I get the list of commands and values that I have registered with Cobra.

If I add a root command and then a DisplayName command.

```
var Name = "sample_"
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{Use: "Use help to find out more options"}
rootCmd.AddCommand(cmd.DisplayNameCommand(Name))
```

Will I be able to know what is the value in Name from within my program by using some Cobra function? Ideally I want to access this value in Name and use it for checking some logic.

Comment: Name's value is obviously "sample_". Are you asking how to read a package variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the value stored in the `Name` variable for performing operations within your program. An example usage of cobra is:

```
var Name = "sample_"

var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "hello",
    Short: "Example short description",
    Run:   func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        // Do Stuff Here
    },
}

var echoCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "echo",
    Short: "Echo description",
    Run:   func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Printf("hello %s", Name)
    },
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(echoCmd)
}

func Execute() {
    if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

`

In the above code, you can see that `hello` is the root command and `echo` is a sub command. If you do `hello echo`, it'll echo the value `sample_` which is stored in the `Name` variable.

You can also do something like this:

```
var echoCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "echo",
    Short: "Echo description",
    Run:   func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        // Perform some logical operations
        if Name == "sample_" {
            fmt.Printf("hello %s", Name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Name did not match")
        }
    },
}
```

For knowing more about how to use cobra, you can also view my project from the below link.

https://github.com/bharath-srinivas/nephele

Hope this helps.